# In Jupyter/Python/Pandas dataframe, Modifying a Date Time field from String to Date Time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I have created a dataframe through an API extract one of the fields of which is Datetime in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I am trying to convert this to a datetime format using the following command:

df_weather['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime( df_weather.DATETIME )

But I am getting errors, the last line of which is:

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2018-01-01 0.00.00')

Is the problem that the Hours field is showing only 1 digit instead of a zero-padded value for values less than 10? If yes, how to correct that?

If no, what could be the problem here and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This is error is not because of hour with only one digit. It is because of your time format is not correct.

You can use this:

```
df_weather['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather.DATETIME,format="%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
```

For time format, you can check this site: https://strftime.org/